# c++ print row and column names in 2 dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, cout

Just wondering if it is possible to print the names of the rows and columns in a 2 dimensional array? What I have is a seating plan with 13 rows named Row1 -> Row13 and the columns are letterd A -> F ... I can get the seating plan to display no problems, but I would like to print out the row and column names also. Below is an example of how I would like the output to look like.

```
Seat A B C D E F
Row1
Row2
```

and so on. I'm just using 2 rows right now until I can get the desired output. Thank you.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    const int num_of_rows = 13;
    const int num_of_col = 6;
    enum row { Row1, Row2, Row3, Row4, Row5, Row6, Row7, Row8, Row9, Row10,   Row11, Row12, Row13 };
    enum seat { A, B, C, D, E, F };
    char seatingPlan[num_of_rows][num_of_col];

    int main()
    {
    int row;

    char seatingPlan[13][6];

    seatingPlan[Row1][A] = '*';
    seatingPlan[Row1][B] = '*';
    seatingPlan[Row1][C] = 'X';
    seatingPlan[Row1][D] = '*';
    seatingPlan[Row1][E] = 'X';
    seatingPlan[Row1][F] = 'X';

    seatingPlan[Row2][A] = '*';
    seatingPlan[Row2][B] = 'X';
    seatingPlan[Row2][C] = '*';
    seatingPlan[Row2][D] = 'X';
    seatingPlan[Row2][E] = '*';
    seatingPlan[Row2][F] = 'X';

    for (row = 0; row < num_of_rows; row++)
    {
        for (seat = 0; seat < num_of_col; seat++)
            cout << setw(5) << seatingPlan[row][seat];
        cout << endl;
    }        
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a direct enumeration for the row and column names, represent the rows and columns as plain integers: instead of an enumeration for the columns, A through F, use a column number, 0 through 5. Instead of "Row1" through "Row13", use row 0 through row 12.

Now that you represent the rows and columns as ordinary integers, it becomes a simple matter of implementing a function that returns the human-readable row and column name; that is, given a column number, return its name ("A" for column #0, "B" for column #1, etc...) and the same for the rows.

And once that's done, printing out the row and column names of your two-dimensional matrix becomes trivial.

Comment: Thank you Sam. I understood the first part about getting rid of the enum and changing it to just integers. Got that changed. Having trouble with the second part about creating a function to switch the ints to human readable. I am a student and the text book they gave us is pretty useless, and I told the school that. If you could please start me off with the function, I would greatly appreciate it. Each time I do try something, I get an error saying: error C2015: there are too many characters in constant

Comment: Here's a hint. If `seat` is a seat column index, what do you think the expression `'A'+seat` will get you? You can't really expect any textbook to teach you how to think logically. All a textbook will give you is the syntax and the description of the language. As far as logical thinking goes, that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:
Modify your code like this:

```
   cout << "Seat " << setw(5) << "A" << setw(5) << "B" << setw(5) << "C" << setw(5) << "D" << setw(5) << "E" << setw(5) << "F" << endl;;
   for (row = 0; row < num_of_rows; row++)
   {
      cout << "Row " << row + 1 << setw(5);
```

....